# Meaning of ~| in Common Lisp format

Tags: character, common-lisp

The CLHS describes
22.3.1.4 Tilde Vertical-Bar: Page
This outputs a page separator character, if possible. ~n| does this n times.

I did not find much for page separator character. Trying it out with SBCL 2.0 on MacOS a page separator seems to be the newline (Ascii 0A). This would make it the same as ~%?

Was it something else in the long history of Common Lisp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me, the output is `^L` - ASCII `NP`, which, when presented to a printer, finishes the current page and starts on the next page.

Comment: On which system is this? I would have also expected 0x0C (form feed, new page). I checked the output of the terminal, maybe it is converted there to newline?

Comment: This is with SBCL 1.5.9 on macOS:  (format nil "~|") => "^L"

Comment: Yes, the terminal seems to convert it to newline. I tried it now with `sbcl --eval '(format nil "~5|")' --quit > test_out.txt` and the file contains ^L (0x0C Ascii).

Answer (score 3):

It's the `#\page` character:

```
CL-USER> #\page
#\Page


CL-USER> (describe *)
#\Page
  [base-char]

Char-code: 12
Char-name: Page


CL-USER> (format nil "~|")
"^L"


CL-USER> (aref * 0)
#\Page
```